# Elastic Beanstalk: changing all site urls to custom domain

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, url, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I hosted my WordPress site on Elastic Beanstalk and I mapped my custom domain to it using a Route 53 alias record. I can visit my site when I got to my custom domain url, but as soon as I click on any link, the url becomes us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com. How do I make all urls appear to be from my custom domain?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Wordpress to know what domain to use for site links, as [documented here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I didn't think that the problem could be on the WordPress-side of things. Thanks a lot!